# Why computing $\sin(x)$ is not backward stable?

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, computational-mathematics, floating-point

It is said in Trefethen's Numerical Linear Algebra that computing $\sin(x)$ shall not be expected to be backward stable, because "the function has derivative equal to zero at certain points", for example at $x=\pi/2$. However, I am not satisfied with the arguments therein. In particular, suppose $x=\pi/2-\delta$. When $\delta$ is sufficiently small, we will have $\tilde{f}(x)=1=f(\tilde{x})$ with $\tilde{x}=\pi/2$. Thus $\|\tilde{x}-x\|/\|x\|=\delta/\|x\|\rightarrow0$ as $\delta\rightarrow0$. Then why is computing $\sin(x)$ not backward stable (at $x=\pi/2$)?

I would also like to know if it is a general rule, that if a function $f(x)$ has zero derivative at certain points then computation will not be backward stable.

Thanks for any comment.

Note: Here is the definition of backward stability in Trefethen's book.
We say that an algorithm $\tilde f$ for a problem $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is *backward stable* if for each $x\in X$, there exists some $\tilde x$ with
$$\frac{\|\tilde x-x\|}{\|x\|}=O(\epsilon_{machine})$$
such that $\tilde f(x)=f(\tilde x)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is not at $x=\frac\pi2$ 'exactly' (where, yes, 1.0 can be correctly evaluated) but rather in the vicinity. Note that the actual $\tilde{x}$ for which $\sin(\tilde{x})=1-\epsilon$ is $\frac\pi2+\sqrt{2\epsilon} + O(\epsilon)$. Now, if we look at values of $x$ around $x=\frac\pi2+\frac{\sqrt{2}}2\sqrt{\epsilon}$ in the midpoint of this range, for instance, then either $\tilde{f}(x)=1$, so $\tilde{x}=\frac\pi2$, and $|x-\frac\pi2|\approx C\sqrt{\epsilon}\not\in O(\epsilon)$, or $\tilde{f}(x)=1-\epsilon$, so $\tilde{x}=\frac\pi2+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\epsilon}+O(\epsilon)$, and again $|x-\tilde{x}|\approx C\sqrt{\epsilon}\not\in O(\epsilon)$.

And yes, you're exactly right that computation won't be backwards stable for any 'sufficiently nice' function $f(x)$ in the vicinity of zeros of $f'(x)$. This is because of the Taylor expansion: Near one of these zeros $x_0$, we have $f(x_0+\delta)=f(x_0)+\delta f'(x_0)+O(\delta^2) =f(x_0)+O(\delta^2)$ and so the 'area of confusion' for values differing by $\epsilon$ is of size $\Theta(\sqrt{\epsilon})$.

Comment: Now I get the point. Nice answer. I also notice an interesting thing, that near the zeros of $f'(x)$ computation is not backward stable, while near the zeros of $f(x)$ with $x\neq 0$, the problem is ill-conditioned.

Comment: Should be also be worried about getting impossible values? This is not going to be a problem for $\sin x$ because $1.0$ can be represented exactly as a floating-point number. But if we're evaluating $f(x) = \sqrt2 \sin x$ at or near $x = \frac\pi2$, it's possible that we'll get a floating-point representation of $\sqrt2$ and it will "round up". In that case, $\tilde{f}(x)$ will not be $f(\tilde{x})$ for **any** $\tilde{x}$, because $\tilde{f}(x) > \sqrt2$ and $f(\tilde{x}) \le \sqrt2$ for all $\tilde{x}$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov That is another way of failing backwards stability — and the two are closely related; the easiest way to get impossible values, as you've noted, is to multiply an extreme value of $f()$ by a 'non-representable' value, and such extrema of $f()$ will tend to correlate with zeros of $f'()$.

Comment: Er, maybe this is the CS in me, but surely $C\sqrt{\epsilon}$ is bounded above by some constant times $\epsilon$ (i.e., $\in O(\epsilon)$)?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble As $\epsilon\to\infty$, yes, but these $O()$ families are to be taken the other way; and $\sqrt{\epsilon}\not\in O(\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.